Attachment added to email as cid shown as noname in gmail
I have a nestjs api, I created a service for sending emails that uses @nestjs-modules/mailer and I used it like this:
const dir = path.join(process.cwd(), 'public', 'email');
const templates_dir = path.join(process.cwd(), 'templates');

const template_content = await readFile(
    path.join(templates_dir, `${template}.hbs`),
    'utf8',
);
const hbs = compile(template_content);

// email content is downloaded from the database
const content = {}

const html = hbs(content);

await this.mailerService.sendMail({
    subject: content[template + '_subject'],
    to,
    html,
    attachments: [
        {
            filename: 'attachment.jpg',
            path: `${dir}/attachment.jpg`,
            cid: 'attachment',
        },
    ],
});

in the handlebars template I have an image like this
<img alt="Header" src="cid:attachment" style="display:block;outline:none;border:none;text-decoration:none;max-width:100%" width="600" />

The email is being sent, but there is a weird issue, if the image is too large, in my case 30KB, on the email list it's shown as "noname" attachment, if i compress the image to  much smaller size, in my case 4KB, it works fine and is not listed as noname attachment. I tried messing with the attachments itself, tried using the default nestjs-mailer service or even bare nodemailer but it didn't help. Any idea what can cause this and how to fix this?
